# Django - Looping through a dictionary using a second variable in template

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

I'm trying my best not to repeat myself in my code but I'm encountering a problem looping through a dictionary by key in my template.

I have two dicts:

```
exampledict={'firstkey':firstval, 'secondkey':secondval}

keys=['firstkey', 'secondkey']
keydict={'keys':keys}
```

In my template I want to loop over the exampledict using the keydict:

```
<tr>
{% for val in keydict %}
<td>{{ exampledict.val }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

I've noticed this kind of combination of variables doesn't work at all, I tried by using:

```
{'firstkey':'firstkey'}
```

And sending that through to the template and later trying

```
{{ exampledict.firstkey }}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

---

**Edit 1:**

Manually going through each key as:

```
<td> {{ exampledict.firstkey }} </td> <td> {{ exampledict.secondkey }} </td>
```

Where firstkey and secondkey is the actual dictkey for exampledict works, although it makes for a lot of repetition.

---

**Edit 2:**

***views.py***

```
def tabletest(request):
    exampledict={'firstkey':'firstval', 'secondkey': 'secondval'}
    keydict={
        'keys':['firstkey', 'secondkey']
    }
    return render(request, 'MinaFakturor/tabletest.html', {'exampledict':exampledict, 'keydict':keydict})
```

***template***

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for val in keydict.keys %}
                <th>{{ val }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for val in keydict.keys %}
                <td>{{ exampledict.val }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ exampledict.firstkey }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

If I remove the `exampledict.firstkey` term, nothing is produced in the table body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Calling list or dict item using a variable in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875924/django-calling-list-or-dict-item-using-a-variable-in-template)

Comment: Yeah, that was me, I realized the problem was more general, calling a dict or list with a variable was unrelated to the loop, so I reformulated my question to be more on point!